php creates *many* session files for one session_start()
PHP v8.1.18 on a Fedora 'test server' with apache 2.4.57
I am the only person logging in or surfing
Today, there were 1345 sessions created ( /var/lib/php/session/sess* )
1344 of these have the same filesize ( see below ) and the same date and time. - no, I did not check them all out, I just looked at a few of the file contents to get an idea.
448 with filesize of 0: -rw-------  1 apache apache     0 Jul 18 08:00 sess_47ca7b49e9ddaa5ef7b8acd796b761e2
448 with filesize of 36: rw-------  1 apache apache    36 Jul 18 08:00 sess_70be9e1ac60c908751c663c3cf894e83
448 with filesize of 157 -rw-------  1 apache apache   157 Jul 18 08:00 sess_841de29c5ef609cf61cce44abd4419ea
the last; 1345th has the correct values for the session.
-rw------- 1 apache apache    177 Jul 18 08:28 sess_2bba3225ee772ec3abe7accf5f31cdaf
Filesize 0 - empty session
Filesize 36 - part of my session values
Filesize of 157 - more of my session values
Filesize of 177 correct session values.
There is only 1 session_start() in the code.
garbage collection will delete them in time, but still.
I expect that either I or PHP is doing the dastardly deed.
Have looked at php.ini and I do not see anything that could cause this. Is this a php problem?  What am I missing?  Where do I start to understand or resolve this issue?

Note: the multiple session: I can not recreate this problem consistently, only happens occasionally - todh

"I am the only person logging in or surfing" How have you determined this? Sounds like you're getting spidered.

Alex - server is on a private IP in my basement. Know I am the only one using it.

Having session files created 8 minutes after the initial hit suggests otherwise. Check your web server's logs to see what's actually being requested.

Alex, you are over analyzing this. Probably a typo on my part. Will check anyway but have to wait for the 'issue' to surface again.

"you are over analyzing this" The evidence suggests that the sessions are coming from hits to your server that you're not aware of. Whether they're coming from your own browser or somewhere else on the network can be determined from your log files. You don't have to wait for the issue to surface again to find out -- just go check the Apache logs and see where those previous hits came from.
